# Contacts SearchAsync takes a long time

Tags: c#, performance, windows-phone-7, telerik

Here is my problem: I am creating a WP7 application and need to list all contacts on the mobile device. I know there is the `Contacts` class with method `SearchAsync` and `SearchCompleted` event handler.

This is all working except for one detail; when I am using the application on my phone, the search takes more than 12 seconds! I am using data virtualization to make the UI draw quickly. I have about 400 contacts in my phone. So the problem is, that `SearchCompleted` is fired after a long time :(

Do you have any ideas how to improve this solution? Should I start inserting contacts in listbox by first letter ("a", "b"... but then that means I need to call SearchAsync repeatedly) and then how can I merge it?

Device: Samsung Omnia 7

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(result =>
{
     _cachingRunning = true;
     var contacts = new Contacts();
     contacts.SearchCompleted += contacts_SearchCompleted;
     contacts.SearchAsync(string.Empty, FilterKind.None, null);
});
```

This method is called almost 12 second after `SearchAsync`:

```
private void contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
            _phoneContacts = e.Results;
            Count = e.Results.Count();      

            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    Cached = true;
                    _cachingRunning = false;
                    CachingChanged();
            });
 }
```

I store `_phoneContacts` and then use it for filtering; accessing it by Index and Count during data virtualization on ListBox.

This method "works" with `VirtualizingDataCollection` (Telerik) and creates ViewModel item which is added to `VirtualizingDataCollection`.

```
public ObservableCollection<ExtendedContactModel> GetContactsRange(int startIndex, int count)
        {
            var collection = new ObservableCollection<ExtendedContactModel>();

            for (var i = startIndex; i < startIndex + count; i++)
            {
                var vo = ConvertToVO(_phoneContacts.ElementAt(i));
                var newContact = ConvertToExtendedContactModel(_phoneContacts.ElementAt(i), vo);

                collection.Add(newContact);
            }
            return collection;
        }
```

Comment: What are your device specs? Could you put your binding code? I've tried it with 1500 contacts and it is pretty quick. Is your UI busy?

Comment: UI is not doing anything... user can meanwhile fill search textbox and when contacts are loaded, filtering in "device memory" and drawing to UI takes just 2-3 sec

Comment: Welcome to the site @Lamiq, I have suggested edits to your question which the moderators will review. Have you tried without the threading? If I understand your code correctly, you are spawning alot of threads which is expensive, especially on a phone.

Comment: So i wrote a "test" app which just shows `DisplayName` of all contacts in device, use `StopWatch` and found out, that SDK method `SearchAsync` really takes this long time (a had over 1300 contacts in device, (I forgot email contacts))... so propably best solution will be searching repeatedly by letters "0".."9".."a".."z" so I will be able quickly show at least some data after start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a Mango device you have a couple of options:

1)Use a background task to push contact information into an application-specific data store.  The standard background task runs every 30 minutes and is allowed to take about 30 seconds to execute.  More info on the background agent can be found here: [Background Agents](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2011/07/11/background-agents-part-1-of-3.aspx)

2)If the background agent is too scary you can do all this in-process.  When the user opens the app up a background thread can gather the contacts list and save them to an internal store.

While you'd need to spend time managing the internal store of contacts, it allows you to control the contact list and will definitely improve the user experience as they'll think the contact search is very fast.